# Parallels plesk 8.5 database

Tags: mysql, database, plesk, parallels

I am having problem creating a database in pleask panel 8.5, i have googed a lot and all the procedures are the same one as this one:

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/plesk/plesk-9/how-to-create-or-import-databases-plesk-9

but once i create the database(wich it does fine), it goes to the home screen and it doesnt let me create a user for any database i create. so when i go to "open webadmin" and select the domain and then the database it says there is no user in that database.

what i want to do is create a database and then just import one that i already have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to have all kinds of ad Blocker and have popups enabled. That solves the problem